# Unable to do a proper check before assigning a variable

Tags: javascript

I have the following code

```
let sess = session

let vigilances = sess.usuario.empresasVigi || 0;
let idSess = sess.sesionUsuarioSessionStorage.sesionExt || null;
let balance = sess.saldosUsuarioSessionStorage.saldo || 0;
```

Sess is an object, but sometimes it is empty so some properties will be missing
If that happens I want the variable to be assigned the value after `||`, so I have written the code above

But so far , im receiving

```
Cannot read property 'empresasVigi' of undefined
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use optional chaining

```
let vigilances = sess.usuario?.empresasVigi || 0;
let idSess = sess.sesionUsuarioSessionStorage?.sesionExt || null;
let balance = sess.saldosUsuarioSessionStorage?.saldo || 0;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Comment: This is correct but it is not supported universally, for example on IE11 (or older).